# reducing siunitx column width

Tags: tables, spacing, siunitx

I am trying to make a table using the `siunitx` package. However, each column is padded with a large amount of whitespace.By changing `tabcolsep`, I can reduce the amount of whitespace on the right of each column but I cannot change the amount of whitespace on the left. Changing `table-column-width` only causes hbox overflow, while preserving the excess whitespace.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{lscape}

\begin{document}
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.2em}
  \begin{landscape}
    \centerline{
      \begin{tabular}{
          S |
          S |
          S |
          S |
          S |
          S |
          S |
          S |
          S |
          S |
          S
        }
3 & 3.20E+01 & 3.13E-02 & 1.25E-01 & 3.75E+08 & 5.07E+05 & 1.50E+01 & 6.67E-02 & 1.25E-01 & 3.75E+08 & 5.07E+05 \\
      \end{tabular}
    }%//centerline
  \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

And here is the version with `table-column-width` explicitly set:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{lscape}

\begin{document}
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.2em}
  \begin{landscape}
    \centerline{
      \begin{tabular}{
          S[table-column-width=8em] |
          S[table-column-width=8em] |
          S[table-column-width=8em] |
          S[table-column-width=8em] |
          S[table-column-width=8em] |
          S[table-column-width=8em] |
          S[table-column-width=8em] |
          S[table-column-width=8em] |
          S[table-column-width=8em] |
          S[table-column-width=8em] |
          S[table-column-width=8em]
        }
3 & 3.20E+01 & 3.13E-02 & 1.25E-01 & 3.75E+08 & 5.07E+05 & 1.50E+01 & 6.67E-02 & 1.25E-01 & 3.75E+08 & 5.07E+05 \\
      \end{tabular}
    }%//centerline
  \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Please advise how to remove the whitespace to the left of each number so that the table may fit on a single page. Thank you.

Comment: don't use `\centerline` it is not really a latex command, just a left-over from plain tex,  just use `\centering`

Comment: @David Carlisle: Ok, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 8):

In the following I used the same format for all columns, which means that there is superfluous around shorter numbers like the `3`. If you want them even closer, adjust the format for each column individually.

The current format `1.2e-1` means

- `1` digit in front of the decimal sign
- `2` digits behind the decimal sign
- `e` needs space
- `-` needs space
- `1` digit in the exponent

As [Mico suggested](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/350439/reducing-siunitx-column-width/350440#comment860728_350440) in comments: To get even tighter spacing you can use `tight-spacing=true` either as option of the `siunitx` package or in the `S` column.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[tight-spacing=true]{siunitx}
\usepackage{lscape}

\begin{document}
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.2em}
  \begin{landscape}
    \centering
      \begin{tabular}{
            c|
          *{10}{S[table-format=1.2e-1]|}
        }
3 & 3.20E+01 & 3.13E-02 & 1.25E-01 & 3.75E+08 & 5.07E+05 & 1.50E+01 & 6.67E-02 & 1.25E-01 & 3.75E+08 & 5.07E+05 \\
      \end{tabular}
  \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. The repetition operator is helpful as well. What is meaning of the asterisk?

Comment: Two further suggestions: (a) use `c` instead of `S` for the very first column, and (b) set the option `tight-spacing=true`.

Comment: @user001 Concerning the `*`, this is part of the repetition `*{N}{String}`

Comment: @user001 the asterisk **is** the repetition function taking two arguments.

Answer (score 5):

We also can play with the different numbers format: some have a negative exponent, others don't. If each cell content is representative of its column, this leads to the second tabular:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{lscape}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
  \centering
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
  \sisetup{table-format=1.2e-1,table-number-alignment=center}
  \begin{tabular}{|l |*{10}{S|}}
    3 & 3.20E+01 & 3.13E-02 & 1.25E-01 & 3.75E+08 & 5.07E+05 & 1.50E+01 & 6.67E-02 & 1.25E-01 & 3.75E+08 & 5.07E+05 \\
  \end{tabular}
  \vspace*{1cm}

  \begin{tabular}{|l|S[table-format =1.2e1]|*{2}{S|}*{3}{S[table-format =1.2e1]|}*{2}{S|}*{2}{S[table-format =1.2e1]|}}
    3 & 3.20E+01 & 3.13E-02 & 1.25E-01 & 3.75E+08 & 5.07E+05 & 1.50E+01 & 6.67E-02 & 1.25E-01 & 3.75E+08 & 5.07E+05 \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's yet another suggestion: (a) Employ a `tabular*` environment (with a target width of `\textwidth`), (b) set the options `tight-spacing` and `exponent-product={\mkern1mu\cdot}` (to economize on space), (c) get rid of all vertical rules (still to economize on space), and (d) use the `table-format` option to specify the minimum-width formatting for each column.

With this setup, it may not be necessary to switch to landscape mode in order to typeset the table.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array,siunitx}
\newcolumntype{T}[1]{S[tight-spacing,
                       exponent-product={\mkern1mu\cdot},
                       table-format=1.2e#1]}
\begin{document}
  \begingroup % localize the scope of the next instruction
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
  \noindent
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} 
          l T{1} *{2}{T{-1}} *{3}{T{1}} *{2}{T{-1}} *{2}{T{1}} }
    3 & 3.20E+01 & 3.13E-02 & 1.25E-01 & 3.75E+08 & 5.07E+05 
      & 1.50E+01 & 6.67E-02 & 1.25E-01 & 3.75E+08 & 5.07E+05 \\
  \end{tabular*}
  \endgroup
\end{document}
```